# How do I change the snapping toggle from CTRL to some other key?

Tags: shortcut, keymap

I'm trying to make Blender snapping function work in the way Maya does,
ie snapping stays on only while the shortcut key is pressed down and then turns off when the key is released.  I see from comments that the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is the toggle for snapping.  How do I change this to some other key?

Comment: That's the default behaviour when you press `Ctrl` if snapping is off. What else is missing?

Comment: thanks Duarte, I'm using a keymap based on the industry compatible set but most of the standard blender shortcuts are different in this case. Where do I find the ctrl in the keymap so I can change it to a different key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find the keymap entry for snapping in preferences and change the setting in the entry.  This one is trickier than most because you're looking for a transform modal toggle that happens to be called "snap invert". This won't show up in the usual search of the keymap, so here's how to find it.  Note this is for the standard keymap.  The process is the same for the "industry compatible" keyboard but you'll have to do a bit of work to figure out what shortcut for the Move command you want to modify.

- Edit Preferences
- Switch to the Keymap table.
- Make sure that the search tab is set to "name".
- search for *trans* It should look something like this:

  [image: Preferences open to Keymap tab with trans search in progress]
- click on the search list and scroll until you find 3D View.  There should be a number of entries for move.  Look for the one where the character is <kbd>G</kbd>.

  [image: The correct move command highlighted]
- Click the arrow to open the entry.
- Scroll down until you find "Snap Invert".
- Open it.  It should look like this:

[image]

- Click on "Left Ctrl".  It will change to "Press a key":
- Press the key you want to use
- Save your preferences if you don't have auto-save enabled.

WARNING: There are many commands that use snapping and each one has many "Snap Invert" and "Snap Invert (Off)" entries.  You may have to adjust one such entry for every tool you want snapping to work with.